# User can't download my app after Google Market Update

Tags: google-play-store

I have a user that is trying to download my app from a Samsung Vibrant running 2.2. But when she gets to the app page in the android market, there is no download button there for her to download! What's weird is once she resets her phone back to factory setting, she was able to download the app, but once the phone is automatically upgraded by Android, my app no longer is available for download again!

Have others encountered similar problem? I have been searching the web for similar issues, but am surprised to not be able to find it. Seems like a pretty major problem!

Some more background - my app does require 2.2 (which she has), permission wise, my app only require the following:

NETWORK COMMUNICATION - FULL INTERNET ACCESS
PHONE CALLS - READ PHONE STATE AND IDENTITY
Hardware controls - control vibrator
Network communication - view network state

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your application manifest isn't making any requirements for hardware capabilities that the device doesn't actually have. It's possible that some capability that you were requesting was taken away in the device's firmware update; if you are requesting any capabilities in AndroidManifest.xml via `uses-feature`, make sure that you set `required="false"` for anything that you can use but don't actually require for operation. Common culprits are trackball and certain classes of multitouch support.

Answer (score 0):

Have the user check their Content Rating filtering options. In the Market app they should tap the Menu button, then go to `Settings -> Set Level`, check the "Show all apps" option and tap `OK`.